Removing Python and pip
I uninstalled Python using control panel but I'm still finding some python files here and there (python 3.10 directory, pip and other stuff related to it) in C:\msys64\ucrt64. I'm removing it because pip isn't working for reasons I don't understand, I decided to remove everything related to Python from my computer and then re-install everything. I'm still getting this:
C:\Users\me>pip help
Could not find platform independent libraries 
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = (not set)
PYTHONPATH = (not set)...
Can I get some help please to remove everything?

Removing Python using control panel
Removing pip using python -m pip uninstall pip command


You might have to scroll down to later answers in the duplicate target.

After few hours, I did find the solution to the problem:

Uninstalled Python using control panel.
Uninstalled pip using python -m pip uninstall pip command.
Manually deleting all the directories left in 'C:\msys64\ucrt64' and 'user\AppData\Local' 'user\AppData\Roaming' that are related to pip and previous versions of Python.

Downloading Python from the website and re-installing it, the installation included pip. Pip is working correctly.

The ucrt64 directory is specific to MSYS environment. You've probably broken something there by deleting any files
